# IoT SIM platform

Tags: gsm, gps

I'm looking into building a location tracker. It will contain a GNSS module and a GSM module, the former for getting location coordinates and the latter for transmitting them over to my backend. I'm looking into IoT SIM providers and was considering the following:

- Telnyx
- Hologram
- Soracom

Anyone have personal experience with any of these? Likes/dislikes, upsides/downsides? Or do you have others to suggest?

Winning points for me are:

- good developer docs for any API the might have
- useful administration panel i.e. beyond just invoices and usage it should have for example SIM activation/deactivation, connected network details, IMEI locking, sending SMS etc.

Comment: This is a very subjective question, which is explicitly [off-topic](https://iot.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: If you want to see it that way, sure. But I'm asking for suggestions with specific technical characteristics.

Comment: @thalisk how would you choose which personal experience is the correct one?